# Using Python dictionary get method with default value as lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I set default value for dictionary mapping in the following case? Without default value, I receive 'None' as response, but I prefer 'Others' as default return value.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'GenderCode' : ['M', 'F', 'R']})
>>> df
  GenderCode
0          M
1          F
2          R
>>> mapping = { 'M' : 'Male', 'F' : 'Female' }
>>> df['GenderDesc'] = df['GenderCode'].apply(mapping.get)
>>> df
  GenderCode GenderDesc
0          M       Male
1          F     Female
2          R       None
```

I know that Python dictionary get method accepts default value as second parameter.

```
>>> mapping.get('R', 'Others')
'Others'
```

How do I set the second parameter when passing the get method as parameter to other function?

Comment: `lambda k: mapping.get(k, 'Others')`?

Comment: You have to wrap it in a lambda function, as stated above.

Comment: @Ch3steR how generalizable is the args=(,) approach? Is it just for pandas apply function, or any python function supports that?

Comment: @zaidwaqi It is only available in a few pandas functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options.

`fillna` after mapping:

```
df['GenderDesc'] = df['GenderCode'].map(mapping).fillna('Other')
```

Or, map with a lambda:

```
df['GenderDesc'] = df['GenderCode'].map(lambda x: mapping.get(x, 'Others'))
```

Or, use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
mapping = defaultdict(lambda:'Other', mapping)

df['GenderDesc'] = df['GenderCode'].map(mapping)
```

Or, use `Series.apply`'s `arg` parameter to pass arguments to the function.

```
df['GenderCode'].apply(mapping.get, args=('Others', ))
```

Output:

```
  GenderCode GenderDesc
0          M       Male
1          F     Female
2          R      Other
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to do this,

```
df['GenderDesc'] = df['GenderCode'].apply(lambda key:mapping.get(key, "Others"))
```

Output -

|  | GenderCode | GenderDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | M | Male |
| 1 | F | Female |
| 2 | R | Others |